# How to make Android Instant App without "try now" button on google play?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-instant-apps

I have to add instant app functionality for specific actions, but we have no need for a trial version.
Is it possible to remove the "try now" button from Google play?
If not, any recommendation for a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try Now button is there from Google's side only. You can not change it by yourself.
App will be available on play store soon after it will be live.

Comment: This should be a comment, isn't?

Comment: It depends upon me, Not you.

Comment: This is SO, it has some guidelines :)

Comment: So, the only workaround is to display a screen explaining that the app is not meant to be used from the Google Play Store?

Comment: Your app will not be there on play store instantly. It will take one day only. You can not remove try now by yourself.